# Can't get multiple results

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I have the following PowerShell code that should run and fetch the last login for the list of UPNs:

```
$UPNList = get-content c:\temp\users.txt
foreach ($User in $UPNList) 
{
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000
$result = Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "UserPrincipalName eq '$User'" -Top 1 | Select-Object CreatedDateTime, UserPrincipalName, IsInteractive, AppDisplayName, IpAddress, TokenIssuerType, @{Name = 'DeviceOS'; Expression = {$_.DeviceDetail.OperatingSystem}}
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'c:\temp\results.txt' -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

However, the "results.txt" file is empty when there is more than one (1) user in the input file.
If there's a single user, results are correctly returned.
How can I ensure the results are provided for all users?

Also, if the user did not log in at all, for example completely new account, how do I ensure that the UPN is still populated in the "results" file, but the rest of the details are empty?
Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you just display to the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to write out to the output file in every iteration, but have PowerShell collect the objects you output inside the loop and then create the csv file:

```
# get the list of UPN's and skip empty lines
$UPNList = Get-Content -Path 'c:\test\users.txt' | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }

# loop through the list and collect the data in variable $result
$result = foreach ($User in $UPNList) {
    # output the wanted data
    Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "UserPrincipalName eq '$User'" -Top 1 | 
    Select-Object CreatedDateTime, UserPrincipalName, IsInteractive, AppDisplayName, IpAddress, 
                  TokenIssuerType, @{Name = 'DeviceOS'; Expression = {$_.DeviceDetail.OperatingSystem}}
}

# now write the collected data to CSV file in one go
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'c:\test\results.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

---

You may also try to do the filtering afterwards like below (could be slower than above code though)

```
# get the list of UPN's and skip empty lines
$UPNList = Get-Content -Path 'c:\test\users.txt' | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }
# filter with Where-Object afterwards and pipe through to the Export-Csv cmdlet
Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -All $true | Where-Object { $UPNList -contains $_.UserPrincipalName } |
Select-Object CreatedDateTime, UserPrincipalName, IsInteractive, AppDisplayName, IpAddress, 
              TokenIssuerType, @{Name = 'DeviceOS'; Expression = {$_.DeviceDetail.OperatingSystem}} |
Export-Csv -Path 'c:\test\results.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

Initially, I checked with one user in **`users.txt`** file like this:

[image]

**I ran the same script as you and got the response like below:**

```
$UPNList = get-content c:\test\users.txt
foreach ($User in $UPNList) 
{
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000
$result = Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "UserPrincipalName eq '$User'" -Top 1 | Select-Object CreatedDateTime, UserPrincipalName, IsInteractive, AppDisplayName, IpAddress, TokenIssuerType, @{Name = 'DeviceOS'; Expression = {$_.DeviceDetail.OperatingSystem}}
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'c:\test\results.txt' -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

In **`results.txt`** file, I got the details of that user successfully like below:

[image]

Now I tried including **more UPNs** in **`users.txt`** file like below:

[image]

When I ran the same script, the **`results.txt`** file is **empty** as below:

[image]

Please **note** that, the response in **`results.txt`** file differs based on how you are giving input in **`users.txt`** file.

I tried changing the *format* of giving input in **users.txt** file like below:

[image]

Now, when I ran the script again, I got the details of those users successfully like below:

[image]

So, make sure to give input for **`users.txt`** file in correct format.

If the user did not log in at all, it's **not possible** to get their details using **`Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs`** command.

Normally, you can make use of **`Get-AzureADUser`** command to get any user details.